# Porto theme - product page type looks broken

Tags: magento2.3, porto-theme

I am sorry for that question, but I am new to Magento and although I was hired as Junior Wordpress Developer I have more or less senior position (except for the salary) and nobody in the company is able to guide me, help me, basically I was hired as a Junior, but I apparently have the biggest knowledge there.

So, I have the Magento 2.3 website, which seems to have a lot of bugs, from what I noticed it was upgraded from some older version of Magento and somebody who did that did not clear the mess.
I managed to fix some issues, but some other seem to be really hard to fix and because of my lack of former knowledge in Magento I am not even sure where to look.

I read all the docs and examples of official Porto theme and from what I saw, when I change  "product page type" to default it should just look like in the demo stylewise/functionwise. It doesn't. Every product page type I choose looks totally broken, like no thumbnail at all, strange behaviour of zooming the pictures except for the grid one, which also looks much different that it should.
There are no errors in console.

What issue might be causing that? How can I debug this?

Comment: can you give me site url so i can check and guide you what is the issue

Comment: this is adult accessories site, but I picked the link with the product, which should not insult anybody (party plate), if you don't want to enter that page anyway I totally understand: https://www.sxy.co.uk/truth-or-dare-party-plates

Comment: it seems working fine with no issue, i cant find out page break

Comment: Thanks. So why is it dislayed totally different than demo? how I can achieve thumbnails? https://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/index.php/demo3_old_en/product-type-default.html/

Comment: you need to import cms page and static block and need to import the demo from admin, make sure to take db backup before importing demo cms page and static block

Comment: thanks, it is not possible, as they only gave me the access to the live page... so I just styled grid images for now, so they look better, for not it should do. Thanks for your kind help, I really appreciate that!